# Postgres + Intellj: Fatal role can't connect to database

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea

Try to connect to the database through Intellj for Postgres. I just keep getting the error message. Not sure if I can include any specific details, because this is connect through IntelliJ so there's not a lot of details I can tell. The progress is running with docker and ./gradlew sDS to kick off the running volume.

The specified database user/password combination is rejected: [28000] FATAL: role "username" does not exist.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, you're connecting to a database server where role "username" doesn't exists. Check your credentials and check the database server and the roles available

Answer (score 0):

I got it to resolved, I'm having another Postgres running on the computer. Just want to mention anyone who have the same trouble as me, make sure to check if your port is not running when you run this command. If after you shut down everything with docker but they'll a port still running then you need to track down and stop other Postgres that is currently running.

lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN  | grep "port #"